# How to show text in textbox based on selection of combo box vb

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox

I want to add this feature within my program in were I select a subject from a combobx, and based of the selection I would like to display a block of text maybe from a txt file or an access database file and display the contents in a another textbox on the form that would allow the user to edit the info.

Im writing this in VB, and I was able to make a combo box and list the different subjects, I just need to be lead in the right direction as to where to start.

I haven't added any code simply because all I have is the basic combobox with the different selections. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to be clear on the source of the text for the textbox and how you're going to access it.  One option is to use a custom class that holds the subject and the description.  If you override the ToString method to display the subject, you simply set a `List(Of CustomClass)` as the datasource for the ComboBox and the SelectedItem cast as the CustomClass will hold the description that you can display in the textbox.